# Why doesn't std::shared_ptr need to know complete type if it's constructed from non-null?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a factory function in **factory.h** which returns an `std::shared_ptr` to a base class in **foo.h**. **factory.h** uses forward declaration to the base class instead of including **foo.h**. As the following code:

**factory.h**:

```
#include <memory>

// forward declaration
class foo;

std::shared_ptr<foo> create_foo_A(int A);
std::shared_ptr<foo> create_foo_B(int A, int B);
void work_with_foo(std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr);
```

In a client code, if a `std::shared_ptr<foo>` was initialized with `nullptr` the compiler would warn.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "factory.h"

int main()
{
    int type = 1;
    
    std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr(nullptr);    // <--- compile warning
    if (type == 1)
        ptr = create_foo_A(5566);
    else
        ptr = create_foo_B(5566, 7788);
    work_with_foo(ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The warning message is:

```
warning C4150 : deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'foo'; no destructor called
```

It's reasonable since the `std::shared_ptr` doesn't know the complete type of foo. This warning can be removed if **main.cpp** includes **foo.h**.

But if `std::shared_ptr` was initialized with non-`nullptr`, the compiler wouldn't warn.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "factory.h"
int main()
{
    int type = 1;
    
    if (type == 1)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr = create_foo_A(5566);    // <--- OK
        work_with_foo(ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr = create_foo_B(5566, 7788);    // <--- OK
        work_with_foo(ptr);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In this scene, why doesn't `std::shared_ptr` need to know the complete type of class `foo`? Is it very different when `std::shared_ptr` is constructed with `nullptr` and non-`nullptr`?

Comment: But the `shared_ptr` already knows the complete type - after all, it has to know it for an object of that type to exist in the first place. The destruction code is bound at the place the first `shared_ptr` is created - inside your `create_foo_X` functions.

Comment: @Xeo: I think that's an _answer_ not a _comment_!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr(nullptr);
```

should not warn.  It is a perfectly valid statement, and has no need to know the complete type of `foo`.  It is likely that it is warning for you because `nullptr` is being emulated.  Neither should this warn:

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr;
```

and the two are specified to be equivalent:

```
constexpr shared_ptr(nullptr_t) : shared_ptr() { }
```

> In this scene, why doesn't std::shared_ptr need to know the complete type of class foo?

The **definitions** of `create_foo_A` and `create_foo_B` will need to know the complete type of `foo`.  But the *declarations* do not.

In a nutshell, the `shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(U*)` constructor needs to know the complete definition of `U`.  But little else does.  There is a more complete survey in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089065/576911

So if you said instead:

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr((foo*)0);
```

*Then* you have undefined behavior.  Apparently VC++ will warn.  libc++ gives a hard error.  Whereas using `nullptr` is quite ok, at least according to C++11.

In summary, none of your examples require the complete definition of `foo`.

---

[util.smartptr.shared.dest]

`~shared_ptr();`

*Effects:*

- If `*this` is *empty* or shares ownership with another `shared_ptr` instance (`use_count() > 1`), there are no side effects.

---

[util.smartptr.shared.const]

`constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept;`

*Effects:* Constructs an *empty* `shared_ptr` object.

---

[util.smartptr.shared]

In the synopsis:

```
constexpr shared_ptr(nullptr_t) : shared_ptr() { }
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I missed this link.

Comment: Can you generate a standard citation that the deleter should not be called if you construct the `shared_ptr` as empty or with a `nullptr`?

Answer (score 3):

So `std::shared_ptr` is three things wrapped up in one small neat package.

First, it is a pointer to some data, with overrides to give you access to it that make using it much like using a raw C pointer.

The second part is a reference counter.  It keeps track of the equivalent of an `std::atomic<unsigned>` that all `std::shared_ptr` copies off the first increment/decrement as they come into / go out of scope.

The third part is a destruction function -- or a pointer to said destruction function, to be more exact.

When you copy a `std::shared_ptr` from another, it uses the reference counter/destruction function/pointer to data of the source `std::shared_ptr`.  So it does not need to write a destruction function, nor does it need to know what the destruction function does!

When you create a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` without copying it, it must create the destruction function.  The default destruction function is one that calls the destructor of `Foo`: which requires the full declaration of `Foo`!

`std::shared_ptr` will call the destruction function *even if the pointer is `nullptr`*, so even in the *empty* case it need write that destruction function.

So the short story is: anywhere you create a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` not by copying or moving from another `std::shared_ptr`, you must either supply a manual destruction function, or you must have `Foo::~Foo` visible (ie, the full declaration of `Foo`).

The cases where you called a function that returned a `std::shared_ptr` copied them from inside the body of the function: within that body, wherever those `std::shared_ptr` eventually came from, one of the two requirements above where met.

The case where you simply create it on `nullptr` it must write and store the destruction function, and that requires full access to the class.

If you really need to `std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr(nullptr);` without access to `foo`, try `std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr(nullptr, [](foo*){});`, which should pass in a do-nothing destruction function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your question is exactly backwards.  :-)

In the second example, where you're calling create_foo_A() and create_foo_B(), you're essentially promising the compiler that these functions, when linked into a program, will return pointers to instances of classes derived from foo.  The compiler doesn't need to know or care what makes up a foo;  at this point, it's up to those functions to decide what a foo really is.

But in your first example, the line:

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr(nullptr);
```

constructs a shared pointer to a foo, and the program is expecting to find a destructor for the the shared pointer to call.  Since you haven't defined foo, only declared it's a class, the compiler doesn't know what the class looks like (it's an incomplete type) and complains about not having that destructor.